# Ng-repeat with condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to iterate in json with question and answers. For each question I have multiple answers. I would like to show each question with the multiple answers. I would like to display. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
q1
 a1.1
 a1.2
q2
 a2.1
 a2.3
q3
 a3.1
 a3.2
 a3.3
```

The json look like:

```
 [{"QuestionID":101,"Question":"q1","Response":"a1.1","CorrectResponse":false},
 {"QuestionID":101,"Question":"q1","Response":"a1.2","CorrectResponse":true},
 {"QuestionID":102,"Question":"q2","Response":"a2.1","CorrectResponse":false},
 {"QuestionID":102,"Question":"q2","Response":"a2.2","CorrectResponse":true},
 {"QuestionID":103,"Question":"q3","Response":"a3.1","CorrectResponse":false},
 {"QuestionID":103,"Question":"q3","Response":"a3.2","CorrectResponse":true},
 {"QuestionID":103,"Question":"q3","Response":"a3.3","CorrectResponse":true}]
```

This is my code so far

```
                var questions = [];

                var answersWithCorrectCheck = [];


                questions.push(test[0].Question);
                answersWithCorrectCheck.push({ answer: test[0].Response, correct: test[0].CorrectResponse });

                for (i = 1; i < test.length; i++)
                {
                    if(test[i - 1].QuestionID !== test[i].QuestionID )
                    {
                        questions.push(test[i].Question);
                    }

                    answersWithCorrectCheck.push({ answer: test[i].Response, correct: test[i].CorrectResponse });
                }

                $scope.displayQuestionsPerTest = questions;
                $scope.answersWithCorrectResonse = answersWithCorrectCheck;
```

Comment: Please show us some code with your experiments, we can try from that.

Comment: Thank you I tried to separate the json into two separate javascript array. One for the questions and another for the answers. And I was using two ul lists.

Comment: Is the problem solved? If not, please share the code!

Comment: Can you restructure your data? It seems like question should have an array of responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with **[angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)**,

```
<body ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'Question'">
    Question name: {{ key }}
    <li ng-repeat="answer in value">
      {{ answer.Response }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/grvBJovYnOfpOsDEPAQe?p=preview)**